# Correct use of abstract factory C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, factory

I don't know how to correct use of abstract factory.
I have example code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
public:
  virtual void Eat() = 0;
};

class Fish : public Animal {
public:
  /* Overrided method */
  void Eat() override {
    printf("Fish eats..\n");
  }

  /* Only fish's class method */
  void Swim() {
    printf("Fish swims..\n");
  }  
};

class Bird : public Animal {
public:
  /* Overrided method */
  void Eat() override {
    printf("Bird eats..\n");
  }

  /* Only bird's class method */
  void Fly() {
    printf("Bird flies..\n");
  }
};

int main() {
  Animal* fish = new Fish();
  Animal* bird = new Bird();

  Fish* fish_ = reinterpret_cast<Fish*>(fish);
  Bird* bird_ = reinterpret_cast<Bird*>(bird);

  fish_->Eat();
  fish_->Swim();

  bird_->Eat();
  bird_->Fly();

  delete fish;
  delete bird;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

In main function I creates Fish and Bird objects using Animal interface, and cast it to Animal pointer, in real program I will use interfaces(for example array with Animals, but we don't know what animal is it).
Fish and Bird classes have their own methods, Animal class hasn't it.
I need to call this methods, but I don't is it currectly using cast of interface to Fish or Bird.
Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is definitely wrong here. Use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` to downcast from a base to a derived class.

Comment: I am not talking about that. I can have many different object types and objects in array which inherits one interface Animal, in this case I must cast all Animal* to Fish*/Bird*/Cat*/Dog* and others. I think it is not correct(and difficult). Or not?

Comment: @Vine If your design requires you to now the actual type of objects and always cast back to them then polymorphism is probably not the right solution. If you have to keep casting `Animal*` to `Bird*` or `Fish*` or other animals, the design is not useful.

Comment: @Vine Quentin is saying that `reinterpret_cast` is wrong here and they are correct. It's actively wrong in the sense that it might not do what you want. `dynamic_cast` should be used when casting from a pointer to base type to a pointer to derived type.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a factory that can return various levels of API availability, based on the caller's needs.  One way to do that is to providing different constructor-methods that return pointers of different types, as shown in the example code below.  For example, if the caller needs an IBird, he can call `createBird()`, but if he doesn't actually need to call `Fly()` or any other IBird-specific calls, he can call `createAnimal()` instead and get back an IAnimal-pointer rather than an IBird-pointer.

```
// Begin abstract interfaces

class IAnimal
{
public:
   virtual void Eat() = 0;
};

class IBird : public IAnimal
{
public:
   virtual void Fly() = 0;
};

class IFish : public IAnimal
{
public:
   virtual void Swim() = 0;
};

class IAnimalFactory
{
public:
   virtual IAnimal * createAnimal(const std::string & speciesName) = 0;
   virtual IBird * createBird(const std::string & speciesName) = 0;
   virtual IFish * createFish(const std::string & speciesName) = 0;
};

// Begin concrete classes that implement various levels of interface

class Snail : public IAnimal
{
public:
   virtual void Eat() {printf("Snail eats!\n");}
}

class Sparrow : public IBird
{
public:
   virtual void Eat() {printf("Sparrow eats!\n");}
   virtual void Fly() {printf("Sparrow flies!\n");}
};

class Pigeon : public IBird
{
public:
   virtual void Eat() {printf("Pigeon eats!\n");}
   virtual void Fly() {printf("Pigeon flies!\n");}
};

class Tuna : public IFish
{
public:
   virtual void Eat()  {printf("Tuna eats!\n");}
   virtual void Swim() {printf("Tuna swims!\n");}
};

class Marlin : public IFish
{
public:
   virtual void Eat()  {printf("Marlin eats!\n");}
   virtual void Swim() {printf("Marlin swims!\n");}
};

class MyAnimalFactory : public IAnimalFactory
{
public:
   virtual IAnimal * createAnimal(const std::string & speciesName)
   {
           if (speciesName == "snail")   return new Snail;
      else if (speciesName == "sparrow") return new Sparrow;
      else if (speciesName == "pigeon")  return new Pigeon;
      else if (speciesName == "tuna")    return new Tuna;
      else if (speciesName == "marlin")  return new Marlin;
      else                               return NULL;  // unknown animal type!
   }

   virtual IBird * createBird(const std::string & speciesName)
   {
      IAnimal * a = createAnimal(speciesName);
      IBird * b = dynamic_cast<IBird *>(a);
      if (b) return b;
      else
      {
         // Oops, requested animal isn't an IBird!  Caller can't use it
         delete a;
         return NULL;
      }
   }

   virtual IFish * createFish(const std::string & speciesName)
   {
      IAnimal * a = createAnimal(speciesName);
      IFish * f = dynamic_cast<IFish *>(a);
      if (f) return f;
      else
      {
         // Oops, requested animal isn't an IFish!  Caller can't use it
         delete f;
         return NULL;
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I gave bad example for illustration my problem.
I have many classes with incompatible methods which can be used only in inheritor class.
Example code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7Wzi8Au2)
And there are many classes with their own methods that can be called from the outside,
they can be called business logic, will castes be used correctly to gain access to these methods?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` can be relied upon to either return a valid subclass-typed-pointer to the object that the base-class-typed-pointer was pointing to, or to return NULL if that isn't possible (e.g. because the pointer wasn't actually pointing to an object of the type you wanted to downcast to).  That said, if you aren't able to regularize your APIs into interfaces with methods that are the same across classes, then a factory class probably isn't going to do you much good; in that case you might as well just instantiate the objects you need directly and avoid having to play games with downcasting.

Comment: Other types of cast (e.g. `static_cast` and especially `reinterpret_cast` and C-style casts) rely on the programmer to know what he's doing, i.e. if you try to use a cast that doesn't actually correspond to the actual type of the pointed-to-object, you may end up invoking undefined behavior.  So be careful with those.

Comment: Btw I don't see anything in your pastebin example that is a factory; rather it's just an example of an abstract interface with two concrete subclasses.  If you don't actually want a factory-pattern you probably shouldn't use the word factory to describe what you are trying to do.